# .remove event triggers .blur event - how to escape that?

Tags: jquery

I have the `.blur()` event bound to an element. Whenever I remove an element with `$(elem).remove()` method, the `.blur` event is triggered for the same element.
Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dhy6E/) - to see the case click on the blue div and press any key.

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<ul id="tr"></ul>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
```

}
JS:

```
$("#tr").on('keydown', '#ti', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
$("#tr").on('blur', '#ti', function() {
    alert('blur is triggered');
});
$('#container').on('click', function() {
 var item = '<li id="ti" contenteditable="true"></li>';
 $("#tr").append(item);
 $("#ti").last().focus();
});
```

How can I prevent the .blur event if an element is removed? Or maybe how can I know that the event is triggered my element's deletion?

Comment: Look at the call stack in the debugger.

Comment: Rephrased my question based on findings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the blur event before removing the item

```
$("#tr").on('keydown', '#ti', function() {
    $(this).off('blur');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can simply call the [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)-function before you remove the element. That should solve your problem. Code:

```
$(elem).unbind();
```

This will unbind any action bound to the object.

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked for my jsFiddle example, but it doesn't work for my real case :(. I checked with $._data($(selector)[0], 'events') and clearly see that 'focusout' is removed from 'events' object, but somehow it still gets into callback function. How can I track down why that is happening?

Comment: @Maximus, you can set a javascript breakpoint in jQuery at the location where a (bind) event is fired and go through the stacktrace to see why it's fired.

Comment: thanks! My bad, I messed up a little bit, it works! :) I marked Roger's answer as ANSWER since it's related to my jsFiddle example (uses .off method) hope you don't mind

Comment: .unbind() has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and it was superseded by the .off() method